# Change event handling in Blazor for child component bound to array

Tags: blazor

I have a model that's binding to the form controls just fine and more or less doing what it's told (which is software is a great start).

The data model is pretty vanilla:

```
public class Enrolment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Parent[] Parents { get; set; }
    public Child[] Children { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Parent
{
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

When I click a button on my "Enrolment.razor" top level form (the 'parent' form, but if I start talking about parents and children too much, this may get confusing), I add one more Parent onto the Parents[] array. Given I may want to add between 1 and 4 parents, I figured I'd do a component to handle that part of the form:

```
    @foreach(Parent parent in newEnrolment.Parents){
        <Caregiver RegisteredParent=parent OnEdit=CaregiverEdit />
    }
```

The Caregiver component looks like this:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="column">
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" id="lastName" @bind=RegisteredParent.FamilyName />
    </div>
    <div className="column">
        <label htmlFor="firstName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First name" @bind=RegisteredParent.FirstName id="firstName" />
    </div>
    <div className="column">
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" @bind=RegisteredParent.Email />
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" @onclick="OnSaveClick">Save</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Parent RegisteredParent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Parent> OnEdit { get; set; }


    private async Task OnSaveClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Saved {RegisteredParent.FirstName} {RegisteredParent.FamilyName}.");
        await OnEdit.InvokeAsync(RegisteredParent);
    }

}
```

What I'd ideally like to do is have the chosen Parent record updated on the onchange event rather than clicking a button to invoke the OnEdit method there. How might I achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a Service here so I'm going to assume there isn't one.

Your data needs to reside in a service.  Probably scoped in this case, but without the overall picture??  Lets call it `EnrolmentService`.

```
// pseudocode
class EnrolmentService 
{

private List<dataitem> datalist {get; set;}

public Event EventHandler ListUpdated;

public dataitem GetRecord(id) .....

public bool AddRecord(dataitem) 
{
  trigger ListUpdated
 ....
}

blah, blah,...
}
```

You can then add some CRUD methods to the service to interact with the dataset.

You components then access the service through DI [dependency injection]

```
[Inject]private EnrolmentService DataService {get; set;}
```

So both your editor and list viewer access the same data in the same service.

The service has a public event, something like `OnListUpdated` which you trigger every time you add/edit a value in your editor.  You can then wire your list component into the event and refresh it's view when something changes.

In general trying to wire components together is not a good idea.

Comment: I've kept this generic and brief.  You CV suggests you need some pointers rather than a lot of concrete code. The MS Docs on Blazor are pretty good.  As an addon to this - There's a somewhat opinionated [Github Repo here](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/CEC.Blazor.Editor/blob/master/Editor-Framework.md) with a lot more about editing in Blazor and a demo project.